# String Formatting for NSC - SQL or Python

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery, substring

I work for a nonprofit and we submit batch queries to the National Student Clearinghouse (NSC) AKA we provide them with data from our database to match in their database. Part of this process means **I need to modify the following fields: "First Name", "Middle Name", "Last Name".  Specifically, this is what I need to do**:

1. Remove all characters, *except* for hyphens ( " - " )

   - For example, if someone entered "Angie", we need to remove the " "
   - For example, Smith-Park should remain "Smith-Park" after character removal
2. Replace apostrophes with white space.

   - For example, if someone's name is "De'Jon" we need to remove the apostrophe, but keep the space where the apostrophe is ("De Jon")
3. In "First Name" or "Last Name", if there is a middle name, or initial, extract the *first letter* as the Middle Name

   - For example, First Name: "Anthony L. " - L is likely the middle initial, how do I pull this out and add to the "Middle Name" field?
   - For example, Last Name: "Mark Smith" - "Mark" is likely the student's middle name, how do I extract "M" from this and add to the "Middle Name" field?

Is this possible in SQL? or Python? Would you recommend performing each operation separately, and then joining the results together at the end?

I understand I will not be able to accomplish all of this. I will need to make assumptions that will result in lower match rates, and there is so much variation in the structure of the names.  The data is submitted directly from families, so integrity is hard to maintain despite the separate fields we provide for each name. I need to determine the best approach that would yield the strongest results, but I would like some other perspectives on how to approach.

The need here is not up for debate, the data quality is not the topic at hand. The formatting requirements are based on NSC's guidelines, as well as best practices communicated to me from customer support.

What I have tried so far in SQL only:

- `REGEXP_REPLACE(first_name, r"[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", "")  AS first_name_no_characters`: doesn't work, I need hyphens and white space for apostrophes
- `SUBSTR(middle_name, 0, 1) AS middle_initial_first_letter`: this works when using "Middle Name" field only. Sometimes the middle name is entered in the "First Name" or "Last Name" field.

Comment: Not really a how-to question. Fwiw if I was you I'd extract the data and use python to handle the data manipulation parts. You could do it in SQL but it just seems like it would be easier to use python and work through each requirement one by one before writing you your output file or however you deliver your results.

Comment: Give it a shot and if you have a specific issue with one of the requirements then post another question specific to that with examples of what you've tried.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a python function that does what you want:

```
import re

name = ['"Smi$th-P#ark!"', '', 'De\'Jon Anthony'] # First , Middle and Last name in order


def format_name(data):
    regex = '[\w-]*'
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if len(data[i].split()) > 1:
            if i == 0:
                data[1] = data[i].split()[1]
                data[i] = data[i].split()[0]
            elif i == 2:
                data[1] = data[i].split()[0]
                if "'" in data[1]:
                    data[1] = data[1].replace("'", ' ')
                if not re.fullmatch(regex, data[1]):
                    part_of_names = data[1]
                    if len(data[1].split()) > 1:
                        part_of_names = [x for x in data[1].split()]
                    full_name = ''
                    for part in part_of_names:
                        full_part = ''
                        if parts := re.findall(regex, part):
                            for party in parts:
                                full_part += party
                        full_name += full_part + ' '
                    data[1] = full_name[:-1]
                data[i] = data[i].split()[1]
        if "'" in data[i]:
            data[i] = data[i].replace("'", ' ')
        if not re.fullmatch(regex, data[i]):
            if parts := re.findall(regex, data[i]):
                full_name = ''
                for part in parts:
                    full_name += part
                data[i] = full_name


format_name(name)
print(name)
```

Output:

```
['Smith-Park', "De Jon", 'Anthony']
```

I could't understand your format of data, so I just used a list.
Hopefully you are able to implement this without a problem!

**Note**: If there are middlenames in both first and last name, suspected middlename in the last name will overwrite middlename from first name, and the middlename of first name will not appear anywhere.